# Printing Firemonkey on Mac OSX 

Tags: macos, delphi, printing, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

How can I print documents with the newly released Firemonkey framework?

Comment: I'll try to make a pdf-based printing solution for FireMonkey - using our SynPdf Open source library and the FireMonkey canvas.

Comment: 3 downvotes?  Unwarranted IMO.

Comment: @Chris: It was even closed for a while...

Comment: Embarcadero has said to expect frequent updates to firemonkey. If some future update to Firemonkey adds printing support, I'm sure Uwe will pop back and update his answer. So maybe it's a "no, not yet", not just a "no".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you can't. According to some information given from Embarcadero during the "Delphi-Tage" in Cologne last weekend, the current XE2 version doesn't contain any printing solution for FireMonkey on OSX.

Comment: Is this still a problem on XE4?

Comment: @Jonesome, Meanwhile there is FastReport for FMX. In addition XE4 has a unit FMX.Printer.pas

Comment: Cool! Thx! (am considering XE4 for a Win/OSX desktop app -- any live apps out there built this way you know of?)